# "UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 10: illegal multibyte sequence" while trying to install lxml on Windows

Tags: python, pip, lxml, decode, codec

Trying to install the recent version of lxml on Windows triggers a weird decode error.

How can I get it to install?!

This line:

```
pip install -r lxml-3.5.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

Triggers this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 282, in run
    wheel_cache
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 291, in populate_requirement_set
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache):
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_file.py", line 77, in parse_requirements
    filename, comes_from=comes_from, session=session
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 413, in get_file_content
    content = f.read()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 10: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to install a Python 2.7 wheel on Python 3.4. Also, `-r` is for installing from requirements.txt files. The error is because it is trying to decode the binary wheel as a text file.

Try using `lxml-3.5.0-cp34-none-win32.whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml.

Just run `pip install lxml-3.5.0-cp34-none-win32.whl` in the same directory as the downloaded wheel.